# Is there a s-grammar for $L_2=\{a^nb^m, n > m \ge 0\}$?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

*Peter Linz - An introduction to formal languages and automata (2001) third edition:*

A context free grammar $G=(V,T,S,P)$ is said to be a **simple grammar** or **s-grammar** if all its productions are of the form

$A \rightarrow aX$

where $A \in V, a \in T, x \in V^*$ , and any pair $(A,a)$ occurs at most once in $P$.

Define a simple grammar or s-grammar for $L_1=\{a^nb^n, n \ge 1\}$ is not difficult.

$S \rightarrow aY$

$Y \rightarrow aYB | b$

$B \rightarrow b$

How about this Language: $L_2=\{a^nb^m, n > m \ge 0\}$ . Is there a s-grammar for this language?

Comment: $a^+$ is a language, not a word, thus your definition of $L$ is incorrect.

Comment: @rici Does concaenaion of two simple grammer generates a simple grammar? $S \rightarrow S_1 S_2$ is not a simple grammar

Comment: @rici concatenation of two simple grammar does not generate a simple grammar

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. Unfortunately, I didn't see your edit because SE doesn't produce notifications other than for comments. You are quite right; those grammars are not closed under concatenation and moreover your $L_2$ does not have such a grammar. (It's not $LL(k)$ for any $k$.)